# Extract gpg fingerprint

Tags: bash, shell, gnupg

I'm trying to extract the fingerprint from a key in my keyring and I can't figure out how to parse the output.

Running

```
gpg --fingerprint 'Identifier'
```

Outputs

```
pub   rsa3072 2021-12-14 [SC]
      ABCD EFGH 1234 5678 ABCD  ABCD EFGH 1234 5678 ABCD
uid           [ unknown] First Last (Identifier) <First.Last@email.com>
sub   rsa3072 2021-12-14 [E]
```

I want to extract the short or long fingerprint **ABCD EFGH 1234 5678 ABCD  ABCD EFGH 1234 5678 ABCD**

Adding a `--with-colons` to the call ends up printing multiple fingerprints

```
...
fpr:::::::::ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDABCDEFGH12345678ABCD:
...
fpr:::::::::1234123412341234123412341234123412341234:
```

What is the best method for extracting the fingerprint for a public and secret key in my key ring?

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ gpg --fingerprint | sed -n '/^\s/s/\s*//p'
ABCD EFGH 1234 5678 ABCD  ABCD EFGH 1234 5678 ABCD
```

`-n` - Silence the output

`/^\s/` - Match lines that begin with a space

`s/\s*//p` - Remove the leading spaces. Print.